# MS Excel bgcolor only for the cell which has numeric value

Tags: excel, cell

I want to color only those cells which has numeric value. Is there any automated way of doing this in MS Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional formatting.
Highlight the cells, look in the home pane for 07/10 or the "tools" (i believe) for xp. click conditional formatting, for 2010/2007 select "new rule".

select "format cells based on a formula"
and type "=isnumber(" and then select the cell you are using, and close the brackets.

it should look like `=isnumber(a1)` for example

apply your color

and you are done :)

further info: http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel